# viewState value is not shown after first postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, viewstate

I'm new to asp.net (after programming for years in classic asp). I'm trying to build a page which adds something to a string.

My code is following:

**default.aspx**

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<p><asp:textbox id="tb" runat="server"></asp:textbox></p>
<asp:Panel ID="tbPanel" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

**Code behind:**

```
Partial Class demo_Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


Public Property gesStr As String

Set(value As String)

ViewState("gesStr") = value

End Set

Get

Dim o As Object = ViewState("gesStr")

If o Is Nothing Then

Return ""

Else

Return o

End If

End Get

End Property


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Dim anzeigeStr As String = ""
If Page.IsPostBack Then
Else
gesStr = "1;"
End If
tb.Text = gesStr


Dim iButton As New Button
iButton.Text = "add"
iButton.CommandArgument = "1;"
AddHandler iButton.Click, AddressOf add
tbPanel.Controls.Add(iButton)


Me.anzeige()


End Sub


Private Sub add(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
Dim myButton As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
Dim addString As String = myButton.CommandArgument
gesStr += addString
End Sub


Private Sub anzeige()
Dim gesArray As Array = Split(gesStr, ";")
For xLauf As Integer = 0 To UBound(gesArray) - 1
Dim anzLabel As New Label
anzLabel.Text = "<p>" & gesArray(xLauf) & "</p>"
tbPanel.Controls.Add(anzLabel)
Next




End Sub

End Class
```

**The problem:**

Pressing the button will cause a `postBack`, but the result of adding won't appear until the button is pressed a second time. The desired result is that the sub displays the correct array within the loop after the first time pressing the button.

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Declare the controls on the aspx(f.e. a `Label`) and set it's `Text` from codebehind instead of creating dynamical controls.

Comment: Hey Tim, 

thank you for your quick reply. Unfortunatly I need dynamic controls as this code is just a summary of my real code... Do you have an idea what to do with dynamic controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the function anzeige() and bind gesStr value to the textbox control each time the button is click. See the code below:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If Page.IsPostBack Then
        Else
            gesStr = "1;"
        End If
        tb.Text = gesStr
        Dim iButton As New Button
        iButton.Text = "add"
        iButton.CommandArgument = "1;"
        iButton.CommandName = "1;"
        AddHandler iButton.Click, AddressOf add
        tbPanel.Controls.Add(iButton)

    End Sub

    Private Sub add(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        Dim myButton As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        Dim addString As String = myButton.CommandArgument
        gesStr += addString

        anzeige()
    End Sub


    Private Sub anzeige()
        Dim gesArray As Array = Split(gesStr, ";")
        For xLauf As Integer = 0 To UBound(gesArray) - 1
            Dim anzLabel As New Label
            anzLabel.Text = "<p>" & gesArray(xLauf) & "</p>"
            tbPanel.Controls.Add(anzLabel)
        Next

        'Bind gesStr value to the textbox control
        tb.Text = gesStr

    End Sub
```

Comment: **Next Problem**

I generate a button in _sub anzeige_ with the same function as the button generated during _page_load_. If I press this button, the labels generated in _sub anzeige_ aren't any longer shown :( Do you have an idea also in this case? Thank you again for your help :)

Comment: If you still have problem, show me your updated code so I can try it.

Comment: thank you for your offer - but i found a solution for that problem :)